# What are a 'coach lines'

Tags: frames, restoration

So contacted a bike restoration place for a quote to respray my BSA, the guy asked me do I want 'coach lines'. Too embarrassed to ask what they were I just said yes.

So what are they exactly?

Comment: Seems kinda ridiculous to be afraid to ask what they were.

Comment: Another technique when confronted by an expert's question is to ask "what would you do?"   They have opinions, and you have an end goal.  Talk it over to see which is most acceptable to you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Coach lines (stripes) are a type of thin stripes you saw on (typically British) cars. They were a hallmark on high end cars like Rolls Royces.

See this image from from [this article](http://money.cnn.com/2015/04/30/autos/rolls-royce-stripe-painter/index.html):

[image]

The coach lines are the lines under the guy's hand.

See also the wikipedia article on [Pinstripes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pinstriping).

My guess is that this bike may have had some sort of pin striping.

Comment: Usually done by hand by dragging a very long (5-8cm) and very thin, fine-haired brush handle first along the intended line. A highly specialized job!

Comment: @Carel - well, the ones on fancy cars. On cheaper cars (which don't have to be cheap; Jags for example), they were imitated by just using tape.

Comment: That's the cheating way to do it. Anyway, craftspeople that could do the job can probably be counted on the fingers of one hand. And the job would carry a hefty price tag.

Comment: The traditional way is also freehand. I doubt a shop will be doing it the traditional way on a bicycle. If you’re into the aesthetic and the price is reasonable , go for it; at a distance anyway nobody’s going to be able to tell how they painted the line.